# Knapsack solution for input of strings

Tags: java, collections, knapsack-problem

I had an online coding test where the problem was described as below. I could not finish the question but did leave some comments on how to come up with a potential solution. I wanted to know what have been the best to solve this problem. The main issue I was having was splitting the given inputs as string and finding a suitable collection to put them in. Below is the question.

You want to send your friend a package with different things. 
Each thing you put inside of a package has such parameters as index number, weight and cost.

The package has a weight limitation. 
Your goal is to determine which things to put into the package so that the total weight is less than or equal to the package limit and the total cost is as large as possible.

You would prefer to send a package which has less weight if there is more than one package with the same price. 
This is a variation of the Knapsack problem.

Input:
Your program should read lines from standard input. Each line contains the weight that a package can take (before the colon) and the list of things you need to pick from. Each thing is enclosed in parentheses where the 1st number is a thing's index number, the 2nd is its weight and the 3rd is its cost. 
Max weight any package can take is `<= 100.` 
There might be up to 15 things you need to choose from. 
Max weight and max cost of any thing is `<= 100.`

Output:
For each set of things produce a list of things (their index numbers separated by comma) that you put into the package. If none of the items will fit in the package, print a hyphen `(-).`

Test 1
Input`81 : (1,53.38,$45) (2,88.62,$98) (3,78.48,$3) (4,72.30,$76) (5,30.18,$9) (6,46.34,$48)`

Expected Output `4`

Test 2

```
Test Input 75 : (1,85.31,$29) (2,14.55,$74) (3,3.98,$16) (4,26.24,$55) (5,63.69,$52) (6,76.25,$75) (7,60.02,$74) (8,93.18,$35) (9,89.95,$78)
```

Expected Output `2,7`

Comment: this can be solved in many ways. i gave one type of solution.  its sum of subset problem. can be solved using dynamic programming also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be up to 15 things you need to choose from. so you have possible combination 2^15 = 32,768. So you can
check every combination and find out which combination meet requirement.

Exampe: there is 3 (1,2,3) things.
then u can choose: (),(1),(2),(3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(1,2,3).
Now need tho find which combination meet requirements.

Here is solution:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in.nextLine();
    String res[] = s.replaceAll("[^0-9.]+",";").split(";");
    double target = Integer.parseInt(res[0]);
    int n = (res.length-1) / 3;
    int[] Index = new int[20];
    double[] P = new double[20];
    double[] W = new double[20];
    int jj = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < res.length; i +=3){
        Index[jj] = Integer.parseInt(res[i]);
        W[jj] = Double.parseDouble(res[i+1]);
        P[jj++] = Double.parseDouble(res[i+2]);
    }
    double result = 0;
    int track = 0;
    double resSum = 0;
    for(int i =0; i< (1<<n); i++){
        double sum = 0;
        double weight = 0;
        for(int j=0; j < n; j++){
            if(((1<<j)&i) > 0){
                sum+= P[j];
                weight+=W[j];
            }
        }
        if(weight <= target){
            if(sum > resSum){
                result = weight;
                track = i;
                resSum = sum;
            }else if(sum == resSum && weight < result){
                result = weight;
                track = i;
            }
        }
    }
    jj = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(((1<<i)&track) > 0){
           if(jj > 0){
               System.out.print(",");
           }
           jj = 1;
           System.out.print(Index[i]);
        }
    }
    if(track == 0){
        System.out.println("-");
    }else {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```